# NVIDIA 520 Open, unable to set the dual monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I created a backup of my system first using Timeshift, then I installed NVIDIA 520 Open. After I rebooted my system, the external monitor is not working (HDMI cable is securely plugged in on both ends)

I then restore my system backup and was able to see my external monitor.

How can I install NVIDIA 520 Open and make my external monitor work simultaneously?

[System Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02FKq.png)

Comment: Same issue here, reverting to 470 works. (But is not the solution we are looking for)

Comment: Update on 470: Everything works fine so far based on my experience but, when I search using the super key (on Overview) pressing the E key gives 2 registers (I'm searching for the "Extensions" app). After the first E, pressing the E key works fine.